# Constructor Initializer List in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer

Please first look the code as follow:

```
class StrBlob
{
    public:
        StrBlob();
        // ....
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> > data;
}
//initializer empty into data ;

StrBlob::StrBlob()
// : data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string> >())      // compile success
{
 //  data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string> >());     // compile error
}
int main()
{
    // this statement can compile
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string> >data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string> >());
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why the statement above  compiles occurs error? ?

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >)
   (std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >)’
   data(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string> >());
```

corresponding knowledge quoted in C++Primer 5th (Chapter 7.5) as follows:

> We can often, but not always , ignore the distinction between whether a member is initialized or assigned. Members that are const or references must be initialized. Similarly, members that are of a class type that does not define a default constructor also must be initialized

First I will share my thought.the 'data' member is default initialized before the constructor body starts executing. right? so,the 'data' member inside constructor will copy the object created from the function make_shared.right?

Comment: Because you can't *construct/initialize* objects like that inside the body of the constructor. It's only allowed in the initializer list. You can *assign* to the already constructed objects inside the body though.

Comment: *"You can assign to the already constructed objects inside the body though"* But you shouldn't make a habit out of it in c++ code.

Answer (score 4):

The first one compiles successfully because you initialize *data* in the member initializer list and such syntax is perfectly valid here. Check [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for more information.

The second one is equal to *data(...)*. It is not a constructing of *data* object, compiler sees it like an attempt of calling *operator()* for the *data* member which is already created (and it says about it in the error message).

Finally inside the *main* function you simply use *shared_ptr* copy constructor to create *data* from the *shared_ptr* returned by *make_shared*.

Comment: you right.  the second one data(..) is call copy constructor ?  but the data object is already created before call data(..).  if so. this means that call copy constructor twice.  it will occur error in the compile. do I say right ?

Comment: Nope, the second is not a copy constructor call. It is a call of `operator()`, which is not overloaded for your class. That's why it doesn't compile.

Comment: I think for a while just now before you disagree my thought.  I try to overloaded the operator () member. and it work.  corresponding the errors given the compiler, I think I know it.   Best wishes to you !   Lastly I want  to ask whether it also may be error because of calling copy constructor twice,just the compiler not report the error ??

Comment: @AndyCong I don't understand how you can call a copy constructor twice. Just a single call in the member initializer list...

Comment: Maybe these are error of my views. I think so much of it. because the act of data(..) is seem likes that the copy constructor,   I think the problem can simplify such the code as follow:     std::vector<int> vec1,vec2;  vec1(vec2);  and then the second statement is just the problem we talk.  does it seem that act of the copy constructor ?  do you think ? I need your help.

Comment: @AndyCong vec1(vec2) does not call a copy constructor, vec1 is already created at this moment. Please, read something basic about copy constructors and object creation, your question is really basic :)

Comment: as I just say, because the vec1 is already created. so assume vec1(vec2) is a copy constructor at the case at the moment(we igore other error). it wiil also occurs error. because it call copy constructor for the object that is created. that is what I mean.   I just talk  the reason it could occurs.   I know it nothing worth to talk about it.   in any case. Best wishes to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize data object later for many reasons, you can use **std::shared_ptr** default constructor in StrBlob initialization list and in the body of the StrBlob constructor - the **reset** function:

```
StrBlob::StrBlob()
 : data()
{
   data.reset(new std::vector<std::string>());
}
```

Comment: I suppose that we should avoid such constructions because this code is not optimal. See Meyers books, for example.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan This is simple example. In practice, you cannot always initialize the object in initialization list, because sometimes you want to calculate some input parameters. About efficiency, I just call default constructor and reset function. I create vector object once. I do not question your answer. In fact, I agree with it. The purpose of my post was to show another solution.